# Solve:$(xy+y+e^{-x})dx+(x+e^{-x})dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation: $(xy+y+e^{-x})dx+(x+e^{-x})dy=0$

Here, $Mdx+Ndy=0$ and $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$. Then the equation is not exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$y'(x)+\frac{e^x(x+1)y(x)}{e^xx+1}=-\frac{1}{e^xx+1}$$ Now we compute
$$\mu(x)=e^{\int\frac{e^x(x+1)}{e^xx+1}dx}=e^xx+1$$ then we have
$$(e^xx+1)y'(x)+(e^x(x+1))y(x)=-1$$
so
$$e^x(x+1)=\frac{d}{dx}(e^xx+1)$$ and we get
$$\int\frac{d}{dx}((e^xx+1)y(x))=\int-1dx$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Now I can finish. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the equation exact by using the integrating factor $f = e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reconstruct the answer by assuming that a solution exists and thus the terms are not random, but connected to each other. Group terms that "belong together", that is, simplify the expression
$$
d(xy)+(xy)dx+e^{-x}d(x+y)=0.
$$
This now invites multiplication with $e^x$, first as it is an integrating factor for $du+u\,dx$, where $u=xy$, and also because it renders the last term integrable.
$$
d(xye^x+x+y)=0.
$$